# Core Data won't let me delete an object with no relationship objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I have a fairly straightforward data model for a Core Data app.  Basically, I'm bringing up
a list of contacts already on the phone.  When a user taps a contact, they're taken
to a detail view screen, where they can select a phone number or email address.  When they 
select any detail item, I'm storing it via Core Data.

I have one entity called `Contact`, and another called `Contact_Detail`.

Contact <----->> Contact_Detail

The Contact relationship to Contact_Detail has a delete rule of Deny.
The Contact_Detail relationship to Contact has a delete rule of No Action.

If a user wants to remove, say, a previously selected detail item, I first fetch the
Contact_Detail objects that have the same ID as the Contact.  If there is only one Contact_Detail
object returned, I then know I need to remove the contact as well from the Contact entity.  If there
were more than one `Contact_Detail` object returned, I just remove that particular object.

It's all working fine, and the database is getting updated as expected (detail objects removed, and when the
last detail object for a particular contact is removed, so is the contact) as long as I just go back and forth
between the peoplePicker and the peopleDetailViewController.

The problem I'm having is that when I select an email address, leave the detailVC, leave the peoplePicker, then
return back to the peoplePicker, and back to the same contact, and deselect the email address I previously
selected, Core Data is throwing an error that looks as though it can't delete my `Contact` because there are
still relationship objects (the `Contact_Detail`):

```
NSValidationErrorKey=details, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1600.), NSValidationErrorValue=Relationship objects for {(
     (entity: Contact_Detail; id: 0xd21afe0  ; data: )
)} on 0x5d5a780}
```

I can verify that the `Contact_Detail` object does in fact get removed.  Why can't the Contact be removed?  And why
does this only happen with a particular sequence of navigation?

Let me know if I should post some code.  I think this problem is causing a crash I'm seeing after continuing to work with Core Data after this first error is thrown.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you set delete rules in this way?

```
Contact<--(cascade)-->>ContactDetail
//when Contact is removed, all details are removed too)

ContactDetail<<--(nullify)-->Contact
//when Contact Detail is removed, this particular detail is removed from Contact too
```

Comment: Izzy - I can only delete a contact after the last detail object is removed (they could have selected 2 emails, 2 phones, etc.)  I could definitely set Contact->Contact_Detail to Cascade, but can only take advantage of the cascade after I determine that there is only one more detail object left.  As I understand things, I can't set Contact_Detail->Contact as nullify, because that means any time someone removes one of say, four detail objects, then the associated Contact object will be removed, leaving the other three detail objects orphaned.

Comment: Nope. Let's say you have Contact with four Contact Details. When you remove one Contact Detail, this detail will disappear from your Contact object and from underlying persistent store/context. No orphans. Result will be Contact with three Contact Details.

Comment: still a little fuzzy to me, but hey, it's working!  thanks guys.